# error in this line :"private String[][] variable=new String[][] {var1,var2,var n}"

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

my question is im getting d jtable but i want to display the data from the database into the the jtable.
if i pass data directly its being displayed in the jtable but i wont data from the database..
please help
 the problem is in this line:

```
           private String[][] row1=new String[][]{jono,jdate,prname};
```

jono,jdate and prname are the variables that contain the data from database.
i need to display it in jtable.

Comment: What types are `jono`, `jdate` and `prname`? They must be of type `String[]` for this to compile.

Comment: And you have no compile error ? no FATAL or WARNING logs ? nothing else than this useless abandonned code line (as we don't know if jono,jdate,prname are null - what you should check immediatly) ?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you declare a two dimensional array but the initialization is just one dimension.

Try this:

```
private String[][] row1=new String[][]{{jono,jdate,prname}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a matrix (2-dimensional array) but are only instantiating single-dimensional objects.

The declaration should look something like this:

```
String[][] row1 = new String[][] { 
    new String[] { jono },
    new String[] { jdate },
    new String[] { prname }
};
```

Without knowing much else about what you are doing, I can't be certain if this would be what you would need, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `jono`, `jdate`, and `prname` are not instances of `String[]`.  Post the error and the declaration of those variables for more help.